# Seeing all store categories under my Appixia BasicCategoryListActivity instead of only primary categories

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, appixia

I added the `BasicCategoryListActivity` module to my mobile app in order to show my store categories.

I'm trying to create a tab for category navigation through my store: show primary categories and only when they are tapped on, show the subcategories.

Instead, what I got is a very long list of the categories in my store - both primary, subcategories, everything... How do I hide all the categories I don't want from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the categories that are displayed in the list are unfiltered. This means that every category in the store should show up - so this is behaving as it should.

What you probably want to add is a filter to the category list.

Add a filter using the `Filter` property of the category list. If you only want the root categories (your primary store categories), a filter on the category `ParentId` is probably the most appropriate. Use the root category id as the value for this filter. If you're unsure what your root category id is, just leave it empty.